# Sending AUTOMATION task_type to CW Logs CDK

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-ssm

I am configuring a maintenance window via CDK and have a `task_type=AUTOMATION`.

I would like to have any logs generated during the execution sent to CW. Ideally, any logging or output for each executed step would be aggregated in CW as a stream. I only see CW configurations for `task_type=RUN`. CDK documentation doesn't show any CW settings `maintenance_window_automation_parameters` under `CfnMaintenanceWindowTask`.

Wondering if what I am trying to accomplish is possible?

Comment: What service is this? CDK will suport anything that CloudFormation supports, but not more.